# Why can't i see a detailed error message in this aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, runtime-error, custom-errors

I have a [aspx page](http://www.justcooman.com/enquiry.aspx) and it displays custom error but i can't see a detailed error message.
My web.config looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <appSettings />
    <connectionStrings />
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <customErrors mode="On" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To see the error you need [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx) **off**, like this:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
```

[From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx), here are the options for the `mode` attribute:

> - **On** -   Specifies that custom errors are enabled. If no defaultRedirect attribute is specified, users see a generic error. The custom errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.
> - **Off** - Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.
> - **RemoteOnly** - Specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host. This is the default value.

## Warning

**Setting `Off` on a live-production site is very risky** as some error messages might compromise sensitive data on your site (like code and paths maybe even passwords).

Comment: I  think that "Off" is the dangerous setting.  CustomErrors off lets the default error, and its stack trace through.

Comment: @JohnMelville you are right - that edit was incorrect and I've updated it - thanks!