# http 500 internal server error how to fix

Tags: iis

I am having a problem "500 Internal Server Error" when I used web service call. What is causing this problem? How to resolve it?

Please advise me..

Here's my code:

```
   MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailAdd"].ToString()), new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailAdd"].ToString()));
    objEmail.Subject = "Test";
    objEmail.Body = "EJSCODE:" + _Message;
    objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
    SmtpMail.Host = "localhost";
    SmtpMail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
    SmtpMail.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MailMsg2"; 
    SmtpMail.Send(objEmail);
```

Comment: Modify how detailed errors are handled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414103/why-cant-i-see-a-detailed-error-message-in-this-aspx-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also you can look at IIS log, that by default stores at C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC1
- there you can find the error description

Comment: At least in with IIS7 and above its this location: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

Comment: IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008R3 in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr1.log

Answer (score 4):

The `500` error code is a generic HTTP error state that indicates a faulty state of the web server.

There can be innumerable reasons for receiving such error. Without further analysis there is no way to determine what's causing the error.

Try debugging your code step-by-step and check the exception being generated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error from a duplicate URL Rewrite value in my web.config file.